# Encrypt database connection for perl and mysql using dbi

Tags: perl, dbi

We are connecting to mysql database from perl using DBI. The connection string has dns as `$dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=test;host=myhost.portal.com;port=3306;";`. But this connection is made using cleartext. We want to encrypt connection.

Which parameter we have to pass to make sure connection between application and mysql are encrypted or secure?

I check, there is `mysql_ssl` parameter, but not sure, does this encrypt the database connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql) seems to answer this directly:

```
mysql_ssl
    A true value turns on the CLIENT_SSL flag when connecting to 
    the  MySQL server and enforce SSL encryption. ... This means that
    your communication with the server will be encrypted.
```

[perl5-dbi/DBD-mysql#110](https://github.com/perl5-dbi/DBD-mysql/issues/110) is also interesting reading.